# nodejs async each function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In node js, i am using async function to get the result from another function and store it as array and return the result. But here i am getting empty json as output {}. See the comments inside code block. May i know where i am doing mistake ?

```
collectSearchResult: function (searchConfig, callback) {
var searchResult = {};
async.each(searchConfig.scope, function (scope, callback) {
  var query = {
        "query": {
           "match": {
           "_all": searchConfig.q
         }
      },
     operationPath = scope.url;

    this.doSearch(operationPath, query, function (err, results) {
        var type = scope.type;
        searchResult[type] = results;

        // Here i am able to get correct output async
        console.log(searchResult);
    });

    callback();
  }.bind(this), function (err) {

    // Here it is just returning empty json like {}. this function is called before this.doSearch complete its task
    console.log(searchResult);
    callback(err, searchResult);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using bind all over the place? What exactly are you trying to do with this function? It looks like you just want to run a query and return a result in a callback.

Comment: removed unnecessary bind. searchConfig.scope is the array of configurations. I am calling asyncly to get data from another function this.doSearch that helps to get data from server.

Comment: And here is the function 
    doSearch: function (operationPath, query, callback) {
   request.post({
    url: rootUrl + operationPath,
    headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
     body: JSON.stringify(query)
   }, function (err, response) {
    var searchResult = response.body;
    callback(err, searchResult);
    });
  },

Answer (score 0):

```
collectSearchResult: function (searchConfig, callback) {
var searchResult = {};
async.each(searchConfig.scope, function (scope, callback) {
var query = {
    "query": {
       "match": {
       "_all": searchConfig.q
     }
  },
 operationPath = scope.url;

this.doSearch(operationPath, query, function (err, results) {
    var type = scope.type;
    searchResult[type] = results;

    // Here i am able to get correct output async
    console.log(searchResult);
    //<><><><><><><>
    callback(); //you need to place the callback for asynch.each 
    //within the callback chain of your query, else async.each
    //immediately finishes before your data has arrived.
    //<><><><><><><>
});


}.bind(this), function (err) {

// Here it is just returning empty json like {}. this function is called before this.doSearch complete its task
console.log(searchResult);
callback(err, searchResult);
});
}
```